# System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> FullName and Type.GetType fails

Tags: c#, .net, generics

When using the FullName of the Type: `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>` I can't seem to get `GetType().FullName` to work, where if I use a `List<string>` it works just fine, so I am a bit confused.

The code below fails, And I am not quite sure why, as it works fine if I use a `List<string>`:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> objectToTest = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();
string typeFullName = objectToTest.GetType().FullName;
Type typeBack = Type.GetType(typeFullName);

if (typeBack == null)
  throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not get type from: {0}", typeFullName));
```

Comment: And what exception do you get?

Comment: I got the error ``Could not get type from: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]``

But as @Marc-Gravell suggests: ``AssemblyQualifiedName`` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the type is in; `Type.GetType(string)` doesn't check everywhere (if no assembly is hinted, it just checks the calling assembly and one or two core system assemblies). If you use `.AssemblyQualifiedName` instead of `.FullName` it will work (as the string produced has additional hints to allow `Type.GetType(string)` to resolve the correct assembly first).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to call Type.GetType on the `AssemblyQualifiedName` instead of the `FullName` as the latter does not take the assembly into account